# Referencing a cell with Offset generates Error 1004 application defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I have to adjust sales volumes so that

1) I do not use up my daily capacity and

2) I do not run out of window by the end of the month

I need two criteria and to run until it either hits my end date or runs out of window at the end of the month.

Dates are in column A.

I have

```
Sub CashCalib()

Set Window = Sheets("inventory").Range("AX124")
Set Capacity = Sheets("Inventory").Range("BU95")
Set Sales = Sheets("Inventory").Range("BV95")
Set EndDate = Sheets("inputs").Range("A1")

Do Until Sales.Offset(0, -74) = EndDate
    Capacity.GoalSeek _
    Goal:=0 And Window.Value > 0, _
    ChangingCell:=Sales
Loop

End Sub
```

I get

> run time error 1004 application defined or object defined error

on the do until line.

Comment: Don't forget to include the error text and tell us what line it occurred on.

Comment: good point,run time error 1004 applocation defined or object defined error.  occurs on the do until line

Comment: For starters your `Sales.Offset(0, -74)` is wrong. I think you switched the row and column offset as you are trying to go left 74 columns but you do not have 74 columns to go left. If you are trying to go up 74 columns then use `Sales.Offset(-74, 0)`. I am not familiar with `GoalSeek` but it does not seem like you are incrementing the cell that is being compared to `EndDate`. So every iteration of your `Do Until` is checking against the same value.

Comment: Holy crap, i feel so dumb right now.  ok so now i'm gonna see if i can figure out the go to the next row part.   i kind of gave up because while testing i kept hitting that road block, i just assumed it was the code and not an counting and declexia error

Comment: @bbishopca - beat me too it on both points while I was typing ;)

Comment: You can achieve the "go to the next row part" a bunch of ways.  You can offset and check row number, e.g.:  `Do Until SomeRange.Row = 999` `Capacity.GoalSeek...` `SomeRange.Offset(1)`  `Loop`.   You can iterate over a collection of cells e.g.:  `Set SomeRange = Range("A1:A95")` `For Each Cell In SomeRange` `Capacity.GoalSeek...` `Next`.  Etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Sales.Offset(0, -74)` is moving left too far as you do not have 74 columns to go left. If you meant to move up then do `Sales.Offset(-74, 0)` or change to which value you need to move up. Just remember that there is not a 0 row or column in excel like many other languages.

Comment: yeah you're right i had a brain fart this afternoon.  thanks for the wake up call

Comment: Thanks for letting me have it.

Answer (score 1):

You were receiving a Error 1004 Object error because you were offsetting one column too many. By offsetting Column BV (the 74th column) -74 columns, you were offsetting to column 0, which doesn't exist.

Modify your Do Until line to look like this:
`Do Until Sales.Offset(-94, -73) = EndDate`

Comment: Sidenote: this is part of the reason why I avoid letter notation for columns, though there is nothing strictly wrong with it.

Comment: yeah i feel like a dufus,  and i also got the row and column mixed up.

Also if you wanna switch the -73 and the 0 i'll give you a check mark, i guess i can ask about the looping question if i keep getting stuck.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to get from BV95 to A1? I guess it would be (-94, -73)?

Comment: no sorry, A1 is on a different sheet and it's the date that i want my loop to stop.  so basically i want it to start on day x and stop on either day Y or until window = 0.  i kind of gave up on the loop part when i couldn't figure out why it was giving me that 1004 error, didn't realize i didn't know how to count

Comment: Ah got it, then I was completely wrong. I will let @bbishopca give the correct answer :)